# How to increase the size of lxpanel in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, lxpanel

Somebody that's visually impaired finds the icons on the panel very small. I'd like to increase the size of the panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click the panel and click "Panel Settings" and adjust the "Geometry" settings to fit your needs.
[image]

Comment: I increased height and icon size but now there's two halves of the panel, the upper one default dark grey, the lower one in a lighter grey. Can I have it look like it looked before?

Comment: You could change it all to one color. This is because the Lubuntu default background image is only as high as the default panel size, so it tiles when you increase the panel size.

Comment: In Lubuntu 21.10, this is now right-click menu button and select "Configure Panel".  Then adjust "Size" to adjust the panel (task bar) height, and "Icon size" to adjust the icons.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the panel, Select "Panel Settings" from the context menu.

You wil see height and width adjust height: you might want about 36 or 48, that should make it easy to see.